# Java script extract all values from a map in an array

Tags: javascript, spring, thymeleaf

Using spring boot,I get a list from the backend,so in HTML:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
   var test = [[${productRecords}]];
</script>
```

By viewing the page source, I found it gives me:

```
<script th:inline="javascript">
       var test [{"productid":1,"productname":"nail","productcosttime":null,"img":null,"counts":8,"bookings":[]},{"productid":2,"productname":"hairWash","productcosttime":null,"img":null,"counts":40,"bookings":[]},{"productid":7,"productname":"jiemao","productcosttime":null,"img":null,"counts":1,"bookings":[]},{"productid":6,"productname":"makeUp","productcosttime":null,"img":null,"counts":1,"bookings":[]}];
</script>
```

Now I want to extract all the 'productid' and 'counts', and assign them to new variables conrespondingly, like

```
var productid = [1,2,7,6]
var counts = [8,4-,1,1]
```

How could I achieve this?

I have tried:

```
var temp = test[0].productid;
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can extract object properties using [map](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/map) function

```
let productids = test.map(obj => obj.productid) //[1,2,7,6]
let count_result = test.map(obj => obj.counts)  //[8,4-,1,1]
```

Answer (score 0):

You can also accomplish this with Thymeleaf if you want (I think the JavaScript is fine as well, just another tool you can use).

```
let productid = [[${productRecords.![productid]}]];
let counts = [[${productRecords.![counts]}]];
```

See [collection projection](https://docs.spring.io/spring-framework/docs/current/reference/html/core.html#expressions-collection-projection).